# Getting "missing argument label" error trying to call Swift method

Tags: swift, function

I'm new to Swift. I have a problem with my simple function. It is not working and Xcode playground gives an error:

> missing argument label 'name:' in call print(hello("txt"))

Here is the code:

```
func hello(name:String)->String{
    return name
}
print(hello("txt"))
```

How can I fix this to have a working function?

Comment: print(hello(name: "Your string")) call function like this. It will solve your issue.

Comment: Did you try applying the fix-it suggested by Xcode?

Comment: Please [search on an error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+missing+argument+label+in+call) before posting a question.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh thanks

Comment: @Hamish new to X-code too! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Missing argument label `'name:'` in call `print(hello("txt"))` 
Try this way

```
func hello(name:String)->String{
   return name
}
print(hello(name : "txt"))
```

You should read the language guide.
https://developer.apple.com/.../Swift.../TheBasics.html

Comment: It works thanks. But, don't you think it's a weakness for swift comparing to c & c++? This way of calling a function makes no sense!

Comment: @Arman In what way does it make no sense? Argument labels can add great information to the call-site. Without looking at the documentation, can you tell me what each argument of the call `CGContextAddArc(ctx, 0, 100, 5, 0, M_PI, 1)` does? Of course, you don't *always* need an argument label if it's obvious what a given parameter does; you can omit them with `_` when necessary.

Comment: @Hamish I mean it was strange for me based on my experience in C++

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an argument label that's the reason:

You can call like below

```
print(hello(name : "txt"))
```

OR you can ignore argument with prefix "_".

```
func hello(_ name:String)->String{
   return name
}
print(hello("txt"))
```